# How to keep original order of eigenvalues in JMAT

Tags: java, statistics, pca

I have a program that counts occurrences of all words in a given scope (let's say, an article). My idea is that I can use several steps from the PCA method- calculate the covariance matrix and then get the eigenvalues for that covariance matrix. Based on those eigenvalues, I can determine which words carry actual information in the given scopes (a set of articles).

For instance, a word that has a relatively constant ***occurrence*** to ***words in article*** ratio in every article is not very likely to carry useful information. On the other hand, words that are often met in a handful of articles, but not in the rest are likely to indicate that those articles are related and that those words carry the "important information"

However, Jmat is returning the eigenvalue matrix in ascending order (which messes up the positional pairing of a column in the matrix and a specific word). My question is: is there a decomposition in JMat that will allow me to get the eigenvalues in their natural ordering? I saw a question that was related to Mathematika and there they suggested using Schurr decomposition, but that's not available in Jmat. Are there any other libraries that can do this?